# 403 error even though the file opens when you click on error in debugger in IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

One of our servers, the production server, has started making 403 errors when I call items in the background using jQuery. At first, I thought it was only in 1 place and added a delay that allowed it to pull up the file. However, there are other places where it is happening.

Basically, if I call a few files with jQuery get commands, some of them randomly will give a 403 error. This only happens on one of our servers, the test server and my local machine all work fine with exactly the same code.
For example, this code

```
function GetSpeciesHelper() {
     
    $.getJSON(`/Filter/GetSpecies/${org}`,
        function(data) {
            speciesSciData = data;
            $("#species").kendoComboBox({
                autoWidth: true,
                dataTextField: "Text",
                dataValueField: "Value",
                dataSource: speciesSciData,

                delay: 500,
                filter: "startswith",
                suggest: true,
                //change: AddNewSpecies
            });
            $.getJSON(`/Filter/GetSpeciesCommon/${org}`,
                function(data) {
                    speciesCommonData = data;
                    $("#speciesCommon").kendoComboBox({
                        autoWidth: true,
                        dataTextField: "Text",
                        dataValueField: "Value",
                        dataSource: speciesCommonData,

                        delay: 500,
                        filter: "startswith",
                        suggest: true,
                        //change: AddNewSpecies
                    });
                    $.getJSON(`/Filter/GetSpeciesCode/${org}`,
                        function(data) {
                            speciesCodeData = data;
                            $("#speciesCode").kendoComboBox({
                                autoWidth: true,
                                dataTextField: "Text",
                                dataValueField: "Value",
                                dataSource: data,

                                delay: 500,
                                filter: "startswith",
                                suggest: true,
                                //change: AddNewSpecies
                            });
                        });
                });
        });

    

    
}
```

Causes a 403 error in production.
I was able to get it to work in this one instance by wrapping the context of the function in a setTimeout with a timeout of 2000 (noting that 1000 didn't work).
I have pages that fire off lots of items like this and can't do this pause everywhere and it is still quite random.
Upon investigating the log files I found the log files don't have a user.identity (email address for identifier) on the ones that come back as 403 (substatus 502).

```
2022-02-16 22:39:56 128.196.199.139 GET /SiteImages/USFS/thumbnails/thumb270bfeeec02-39d2-4d4e-a6d5-07717c13e9d9.jpg - 443 <useremail>@email.arizona.edu 69.137.182.140 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/98.0.4758.102+Safari/537.36 url 200 0 0 93
```

compared to

`2022-02-16 22:39:56 128.196.199.139 GET /SiteImages/USFS/thumbnails/thumb27008d39b70-daac-456f-8586-c5d56fdf9fcd.jpg - 443 - 69.137.182.140 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/98.0.4758.102+Safari/537.36 url 403 502 0 93`

Does anyone know what is going on or how to fix this?

Comment: `403 Error` is related to permissions. You will want to check the File Permissions to ensure IIS can Read the files based on the Request. Check your IIS Logs as well. Sounds like the request may not be the same when you use AJAX. Please post your Code and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I feel like you didn't read to the end of the post. But I have a way in code that was able to the 403 to a 200 so I added this to the ticket.

Comment: I read through it a few times before making my comment. Consider this: GET Request for page arrives with IIS, attempts to Read the file from Root Path and gets Access Denied. IIS responds with the 403 Status. Some time passes and another GET request arrives for the same file. IIS attempts to read the file and is Access Allowed, responds with a 200 Status. Based on your example, there is no way to know what `/Filter/GetSpecies/${org}` results as, I am guessing either an ASP page or just a URL which may be Rewriting to another file. Neither should be responding with a 403 on the first request.

Comment: I see the Log entries and as you pointed out, there seems to be some degree of authentication happening with one and not the other. Does the Script create a Session or Cookie? Is that happening initially or is it not available up front on the first request? How easy is it to replicate the issue? Like do you have to clear cache to replicate it within 20 minutes?

Comment: *403.502 - Forbidden: Too many requests from the same client IP; Dynamic IP Restriction Maximum request rate limit reached.* You might have too many sustaining connections being opened by your scripts. use `netsh -anp tcp` and observe the HTTP and HTTPS connections. If IIS has too many OPEN connections, it may reject new concurrent connections. You may also want to check your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Twisty who had me look at the Dynamic Ip Restriction Maximum.
This was sent low to a DOS attack and it was too low for the actual application.
This was found in the IP REstrictions->Dynamic Restrictions link in IIS.